# Syntax for Multiple Selectors in jQuery when using OR

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to execute some javascript if button 1 is pressed OR button 2 is pressed.

I'm using the notation pasted below, (The code below does not work but I've supplied it to illustrate what I am trying to do).  I know I can wrap up the code to execute into another function, and then write two blocks of code (1 for each button) but I'd just like to learn if there's a way to do a conditional OR selector in jQuery using the type of sytnax below.  Thanks!

```
$(".btn1.btn2").click(function(){
  //execute code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma for multiple selections in one call. The example below selects all elements that have class btn1 and/or btn2

```
$(".btn1, .btn2").click(function(){
  //execute code
}
```

Comment: thanks!  i always find learning the syntax takes the longest :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btn1, #btn2").click(function(){
  //execute code
}
```

if you have id's for the button.

```
$(".btn1, .btn2").click(function(){
  //execute code
}
```

if you want to access them using class name.